# Does ASP.NET MVC have the App_Code concept?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does ASP.NET MVC have the App_Code concept?

Answer (score 6):

There's no App_Code directory for MVC projects because they are basically Web Application Projects, not Web Site projects.

App_Code is useful for external code or small amounts of utility code that you wish to get compiled into a website.  But since MVC is a framework for handling the web requests by itself, you wouldn't (usually) want to be including it as some piece of code in another application.  Conversely, you also don't need to be adding code to a special place to make sure it gets compiled, like you would with a web site project.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way although the default way in the templates is to use a compiled class library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MVC does have the app_code concept.  You can put all your controllers and models and helpers in app_code and get them all to dynamically compile.